# Grabbing year from ComboBox before inserting into DATE function

Tags: excel, vba

Continuing on my automation quest, I'm trying to have a ComboBox populated with years ranging from 2021 to 2023. These years allow the user to select the total withdraws by branch month-by-month for a year across the multiple accounts we have at my workplace.

The issue I'm having might be syntax-based, but when trying to insert the ComboBox.value into the Date function, it seems to not recognize it.

Below is the code for the ComboBox;

```
With ComboBox2
    .AddItem "2021"
    .AddItem "2022"
    .AddItem "2023"
End With
```

And this is a snippet of the code for my month-to-month sums with this snippet being for our West Branch specific Engineering Experts account in Jan:

```
Me.TextBox19.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("West Branch").Evaluate("(SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"">=""&DATE(ComboBox2.Value,1,1),B:B,""<=""&DATE(ComboBox2.Value,1,31),E:E,""Engineering Experts""))*(-1)"))
```

I've tried the following:

- Convert the ComboBox2.Value into an integer
- `""&DATE(""ComboBox2.Value"",1,31)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the value `ComboBox2.Value` outside the string with `&` as follows:

```
Me.TextBox19.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("West Branch").Evaluate("(SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"">=""&DATE(" & ComboBox2.Value & ",1,1),B:B,""<=""&DATE(" & ComboBox2.Value & ",1,31),E:E,""Engineering Experts""))*(-1)"))
```

I recommend to incude a check so that `ComboBox2.Value` is a valid year if you haven't a check yet:

```
If IsNumeric(ComboBox2.Value) Then
    If ComboBox2.Value >= 1900 And ComboBox2.Value <= 9999 Then
        Me.TextBox19.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("West Branch").Evaluate("(SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"">=""&DATE(" & ComboBox2.Value & ",1,1),B:B,""<=""&DATE(" & ComboBox2.Value & ",1,31),E:E,""Engineering Experts""))*(-1)"))
    End If
End If
```

Note that if you put a year `<1900` into `DATE()` it considers it to be the amounts of years **after** `1900` so if you put `DATE(1899,1,1)` it will consider it `1899` after `1900` and come up with `3799-01-01` as date because Excel formulas cannot handle dates before `1900`.

Comment: That solved it; thank you!